# Concatenate MultiIndex DataFrames with column headers

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation, multi-index

I am concatenating several Pandas DataFrames into one big DataFrame to print the results to a CSV file.

I am reporting several segments over a multi-period calculation horizon (e.g. 0 through 3). Each segment has several DataFrames associated with it (e.g. df1 & df2).
For simplification, just one segment is assumed here (each different segment has a specific key or scenario key).

Everything works fine, except for printing the column names to CSV.
I tried `pd.concat(..., names = " ... ")` - but that does not work. The only thing that is printed to the headers is different dates.

Specifically, I would like to print "Full Key", "Scenario" and "Metric" to the column headers of the CSV (in columns 0, 1, and 2) and continue to print the periods (in columns 3 through 6).

Is there a simple way to do this in Pandas?

Example

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dates = [0, 1, 3, 3]
labels1 = ["A", "B", "C"]
labels2 = ["X", "Y", "Z"]
rand1 = np.random.rand(3,4)
rand2 = np.random.rand(3,4)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(rand1, columns=dates, index=labels1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(rand2, columns=dates, index=labels2)

# Differs for each segment (note: just one segment assumed here for simplification)
key = "rand_key"
scenario = "scenario"

df_con = pd.concat([df1, df2], keys=pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [[key], [scenario], ["Data Frame 1", "Data Frame 2"]],
    names=['Full Key', 'Scenario', 'Metric']))

print(df_con)
```

Output

```
                                         0         1         3         3
rand_key scenario Data Frame 1 A  0.381607  0.251023  0.225814  0.221244   
                               B  0.829346  0.148782  0.601416  0.410067   
                               C  0.785393  0.792234  0.012604  0.476273   
                  Data Frame 2 X  0.960281  0.563819  0.286736  0.530170   
                               Y  0.829257  0.986729  0.790758  0.013667   
                               Z  0.287239  0.796072  0.576769  0.694845
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use parameter `names` in [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html), not in [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html):

```
df_con = pd.concat([df1, df2], 
                   keys=pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
                        [[key], [scenario], ["Data Frame 1", "Data Frame 2"]]), 
                   names=["Full Key", "Scenario","Metric", 'val'])

print(df_con)
                                           0         1         3         3
Full Key Scenario Metric       val                                        
rand_key scenario Data Frame 1 A    0.824102  0.525212  0.386341  0.590881
                               B    0.137524  0.808270  0.965826  0.779796
                               C    0.239335  0.867260  0.808115  0.063681
                  Data Frame 2 X    0.231228  0.589685  0.137487  0.678441
                               Y    0.992191  0.285752  0.760913  0.046527
                               Z    0.332536  0.944553  0.636517  0.601849
```

If need remove level `val`:

```
df_con = df_con.reset_index(level='val', drop=True)
print (df_con)
                                       0         1         3         3
Full Key Scenario Metric                                              
rand_key scenario Data Frame 1  0.686811  0.726811  0.479694  0.367657
                  Data Frame 1  0.839970  0.454164  0.321366  0.092720
                  Data Frame 1  0.060438  0.090951  0.682706  0.680736
                  Data Frame 2  0.243174  0.640461  0.069139  0.872920
                  Data Frame 2  0.109607  0.169056  0.467378  0.775949
                  Data Frame 2  0.854445  0.210386  0.076642  0.788915
```

Last write to `csv`:

```
df_con.to_csv('file.csv')
```

---

Another solution is set index names:

```
df_con.index.names = ["Full Key", "Scenario","Metric", 'val']
df_con.to_csv('file.csv')
```

Last solution is [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df_con.rename_axis(["Full Key", "Scenario","Metric", 'val']).to_csv('file.csv')
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! The first suggestion solved my problem. Just a simple bracket in the wrong place :-)